# Get Rid of Edit with Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 from Context Menu?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, dreamweaver

This really bothers me. How do I get rid of that context menu not only on .txt files, but any file type?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Nirsoft ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) - Should be able to remove it no problem!

However, I have not ever tested uninstalling after - so you may want to backup just in case, but I can't imagine there being a problem. I use this tool a lot.

Comment: Is that a portable program I can run without installing and then delete after? I hate to install software for stuff like this.

Comment: No install required, single EXE in a zip

Comment: Glad to hear!  .